# Command to run the Entity Framework .cs files to create database tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have just pulled the solution of C# rest API. In the solution under web project I have a `Migration` folder which contains a number of `.cs` files to create table in database.

The files are like `84618186***_InititalCreate`, `68686186***_AddXyz`, `86454186***_ExtendXyz`. I have absolutely no knowledge about Entity Framework.

I tried the `Add-Migration` command but it added a file. `Update-database` added some tables to the database but remaining tables are still not created. What my little experience about this says is there must be a command which will create the tables in SQL Server from all these files.

So I just want to know how to do it. reference to any specific link on stack will also help I did searched for half an hour but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: `Update-database` is that command ....

Comment: `I tried the Add-Migration command but it added a file.` Which is exactly what it's supposed to do. That file contains the commands to execute against the database, and is also used to create a record in your `Migrations` table.

Comment: So are you trying to create a new database out of existing migrations or update an existing database to match the current code model?

Comment: @marc_s : Found that the tables which were not created are dropped in the scripts below it. The update-databse is  the command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new database, change your connection string to point to the new, empty database. Then you can create an idempotent script that will walk through all the migrations and apply them:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent

Another alternative would be to temporarily change your database initializer to one that recreates the database like DropCreateDatabaseAlways then switch it back.

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/